# WSL2 DDEV startup problem (Error response from daemon: Ports are not available)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wsl-2, ddev

I have a problem with DDEV. I'm running Docker Desktop 4.13.1, DDEV 1.21.3, WSL2, and Windows 11. After updating Docker Desktop 4.18.0 to and DDEV to 1.21.6, I encountered a problem with ports.

There are several situations, but in each case, the my-site.ddev.site page doesn't work.

**First case:**
The ports I have set:

```
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
```

Error:

```
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:443: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
Failed to start my-site: failed to start ddev-router: ComposeCmd failed to run 'COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=ddev-my-site docker-compose -f /home/hp/.ddev/.router-compose-full.yaml -p ddev-router up -d', action='[-p ddev-router up -d]', err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='Container ddev-router Creating
Container ddev-router Created
Container ddev-router Starting
Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 127.0.0.1:443 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:443: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.'
```

**Second case:**
When I change the ports to:

```
router_http_port: "8000"
router_https_port: "8443"
```

DDEV starts up, but when I go to the my-site.ddev.site page, Chrome (and other browsers) returns an error:
The my-site.ddev.site server unexpectedly terminated the connection.

I tried manually adding 127.0.0.1 my-site.ddev.site to the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`), but unfortunately, it didn't work.

```
127.0.0.1 my-site.ddev.site
```

I downgraded Docker from 4.18.0 to 4.13.1 and DDEV from 1.21.6 to 1.21.3, but it didn't help.

I also tried starting the DDEV project on port 443 and 80 using the following method:

```
Win11 PowerShell net stop winnat
WSL2 ddev start
Win11 PowerShell net start winnat
```

but that also didn't work.

I also tried:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

And it also did nothing. I have tried a lot of methods, but none of what I tried worked. What I wrote above are most common solutions I found online.

Unfortunately ChatGPT also doesn't know any reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSL2 has been having some rough times with recent upgrades, and it sounds like you have some of those going on.

Please take a look at https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/4809

Also https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/4573

You may want to consider moving from Docker Desktop to Docker-inside-WSL2, but I'm not sure that will affect these issues. If you do that, make sure you have database dumps or snapshots.

Comment: updating WSL2 to pre-release and reinstalling DDEV helped. Solution:
wsl --update --pre-release
sudo apt-get remove ddev && sudo apt-get install ddev

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Updating WSL2 to pre-release and reinstalling DDEV helped. Solution:

```
wsl --update --pre-release
sudo apt-get remove ddev && sudo apt-get install ddev
```